# Lex: match ignore space

Tags: regex, lex

I have a work to recognize hex number,
my problem is how to ignore space, but not allow any character before.
like this:

```
0x7f6e ---->match,and print"0x7f6e"
    0X2146 ---->match,and print"0X21467"
acns0x8972 ----> not match
```

my work now:

```
hex     \s*0[X|x][0-9a-fA-f]{1,4}(^.)*(\n)

{hex}   { ECHO;}
.|\n    {}
```

and it print:

```
0x7f6e
    0X2146
```

how can i print it without space?
like this:

```
0x7f6e
0X2146
```

Comment: You could use an extra rule which eats up spaces at line start: `^[ \t]+ { }`. In this case, `\s` may be reomved from start of `hex`.

Comment: @Scheff Thank for your comment.I put`^[ \t]+ { }`before`{hex}   { ECHO;}`, and get the result:`0x7f6e\n0X2146\n0x8972.But 0x8972 is not match.`

Comment: Is this the expected result?

Comment: No.The current result include 0x8972, but i do not want it.

Comment: This is because your last pattern `.|\n` accepts the unexpected characters. Thus, the `{hex}` can apply even if the line starts with anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a working version which should do what you expect:

```
%{
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%%

^[ \t]*0[Xx][0-9a-fA-f]{1,4}(.*)$ {
  /* skip spaces at begin of line */
  const char *bol = yytext;
  while (isspace((unsigned char)*bol)) ++bol;
  /* echo rest of line */
  puts(bol);
}

.|\n { }

%%

int main(int argc, char **argv) { return yylex(); }

int yywrap() { return 1; }
```

Notes:

1. `\s` seems to be unsupported (at least in my version 2.6.3 of flex). I replaced it by `[ \t]`. Btw. `\s` usually matches also carriage return, newline, formfeed what's not intended in my case.
2. `(^.)*` replaced by `(.*)`. (I didn't understand the intention of the original one. Mistake?)
3. I added a `^` at begin of 1st pattern so that pattern is attached to begin of line.
4. I replaced `\n` at the end of hex line with `$`. The `puts()` function adds a newline to output. (Newlines are always matched by 2nd rule and thus skipped.)
5. I replaced `ECHO;` with some C code to (1st) remove spaces at begin of line and (2nd) output the rest of line to standard output channel.

Compiled and tested in cygwin on Windows 10 (64 bit):

```
$ flex --version
flex 2.6.3

$ flex -o test-hex.c test-hex.l ; gcc -o test-hex test-hex.c

$ echo "
0x7f6e                                              
    0X2146
acns0x8972
" | ./test-hex
0x7f6e
0X2146

$
```

Note: I used `echo` to feed your sample data via pipe into standard input channel of `test-hex`.

Comment: I get the correct answer through your method, but i hope there is a way to use stdin and get correct answer.No matter what, thank you for taking the time on this problem.